# How to confirm core data execution

Tags: swift, core-data, swift3

I am trying to confirm if all the data in core data has been deleted with following source (where "CoreDataHelper.getCoreDataHelper().context" is NSManagedObjectContext)

```
public static func delete(predicates: [NSPredicate] = []) {
    let fetchRequest = request(predicates: predicates)
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    do {
        let result1 = try CoreDataHelper.getCoreDataHelper().context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        NSLog("Delete batch size: %d", result1.count)
        let result2 = try CoreDataHelper.getCoreDataHelper().context.execute(deleteRequest)
        NSLog("Delete request succeeded: %d", result2)
    } catch {
        NSLog("Delete request failed")
        return
    }
}
```

When I test it, following is shown in the log

> Delete batch size: 1
>
> Delete request succeeded: 250432

But when I actually see the data, it seems that it is not deleted.
I try to add a data as following an error occurs that data is already in the core data.

```
public static func add(from object: Dictionary<String, Any>) -> NSManagedObjectProtocol? {
    let exists = fetch(id: object)
    if exists.count > 0 {
        NSLog("Object already exists in CoreData : %@", object.description)
        return nil
    } else {
        return newObject(object: object) as NSManagedObjectProtocol
    }
}
```

> Object already exists in CoreData : ....

So my question is how do I know that execute function of NSBatchDeleteRequest worked correctly. Is there a return value that we can use to confirm if there was no error in the execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save your `NSManagedContext` after deleting:

```
public static func delete(predicates: [NSPredicate] = []) {
    let fetchRequest = request(predicates: predicates)
    let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: fetchRequest)
    do {
        ...
        let result2 = try CoreDataHelper.getCoreDataHelper().context.execute(deleteRequest)
        //save context
        try CoreDataHelper.getCoreDataHelper().context.save()
    } catch {
        NSLog("Delete request failed")
        return
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it true that the context does not have to be saved at every delete request? Core data should be able to know the status of the data regardless of save action.

Comment: By the way, some test cases succeeded to delete the data but some did not. So I still need to know if the result of the delete was successful or not, or at least know how many rows were affected.

Comment: We need to know more about your Core Data Stack to help further.

Comment: It seemed that I had to save context at when creating a new object.

Comment: It depends on your Core Data stack. I.e. if you are using more than one context, how they are setup to interact with each other (parent/child contex, automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent setting on the contexts ...).

Comment: Nope. I am not doing anything fancy.

Comment: Maybe you do not know. We can only guess without seeing code.

Comment: I printed out my context when ever I used, and it seems that the memory address is always the same. Isn't that how I should check the context is always same?

Comment: If you checked the same context in all methods (`fetch(id:)` ...), yes. In this case, the issue should not show up. I suspect `fetch(id:)` is somehow causing the issue.